# Localhost Not Working After Creating Virtual Host in XAMPP

Tags: php, apache, configuration, xampp, virtualhost

I created a virtual host for my project "phpiggy" using XAMPP for Apache and PHP. Here's the configuration I added to `httpd-vhosts.conf`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/CMPD/phpiggy/public"
ServerName phpiggy.local
</VirtualHost>
```

I also added this line to the `hosts` file:

```
127.0.0.1 phpiggy.local
```

After restarting Apache, typing "**phpiggy.local**" in the browser URL works correctly and points to the intended directory.

However, when I type "**localhost**" in the browser URL, it doesn't show the default files/folders under `htdocs` as expected.

Is this normal behavior? After creating a virtual host, can't I use localhost anymore to access other files in `htdocs`, only the directory specified in the virtual host?

While writing this, I tried reenabling the usual localhost by commenting the lines I added in httpd-vhosts.conf and the hosts file and then I uncomment and then tried again and did that a few times. Now, even after I wrote those codes in the `httpd-vhosts.conf` and `hosts`, when I typed "phpiggy.local" in the browser URL, now it says

```
ERROR
The requested URL could not be retrieved
```

Edit: Now, I realized when I type "**localhost**", it is routing to the files/folder under `C:/xampp/htdocs/CMPD/phpiggy/public` and when I type "**phpiggy.local**" I get an error as I said above.

I hope to be able to be able to access the files/folders under `htdocs` by typing "**localhost**" in the URL and if possible and not a very hassle to do, then I would like to access to the files/folder under `C:/xampp/htdocs/CMPD/phpiggy/public` when type "**phpiggy.local**"

Comment: Why not add two virtual host entries, one for localhost that points to your htdocs directory and the other that points at the phpiggy.local directory. 

You should also have an entry for 127.0.0.1 in your hosts file.

Comment: I attempted that as well. However, no matter what I try, I consistently encounter the error message "The requested URL could not be retrieved" when I simply type "phpiggy.local" in the URL. I've tried by routing `htdocs` to `localhost`, and also, routing `phpiggy/public` to `phpiggy.local`, within the `httpd-vhosts.conf` file. I ensured that both `127.0.0.1 localhost` and `127.0.0.1 phpiggy.local` are listed in the hosts file. Despite these attempts, I still cannot access `phpiggy/public` when entering only `phpiggy.local`. The error persists.

Comment: Can you please show us what your full virtual host setup looks like now?

Comment: I commented out the configuration settings I had previously written in the `httpd-vhosts.conf` and `hosts` files after my last attempts. As you requested, I then rewrote those settings in both files to show you the images of the configurations. Now, when I type **localhost**, it displays the htdocs directory, and when I type **phpiggy.local**, it shows the phpiggy/local directory. I believe it's working now, perhaps due to the order in which I wrote the configuration settings in both files. Initially, I might have created the virtual host for phpiggy.local first and then localhost, ...

Comment: ... while in the hosts file, I had `127.0.0.1 localhost` listed first, followed by phpiggy.local. I don't recall the exact order. Alternatively, it could be because this time I stopped the Apache server before writing the configuration settings, whereas previously, the Apache server was running while I made the changes. Although, I did restart the Apache server after modifying the configurations in both cases.

I'm unsure what specifically resolved the issue this time.
Anyway, thank you for trying to help.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I think I found a solution. Instead of just only restarting the Apache server by turning off and on again after making changes in the configuration settings, also restart your laptop. Because for me, only by also restarting the laptop after making changes affects the configuration changes. When I don't restart my laptop and make changes, it gives me the error I described in the question.